I don't understand how QPSK modulation is involved with or assists in carrier suppression
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/quadrature-phase-shift-keying-qpsk-modulation/
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/radio-frequency-demodulation/understanding-i-q-signals-and-quadrature-modulation/#:~:text=I%2FQ%20signaling%20refers%20to,that%20involves%20I%2FQ%20signals
These are the references that were recommended to me on QPSK modulation. I have read that by manipulating the two quadrature carriers and adding them, the original carrier information gets "canceled out" to a large extent. If you add I and Q signals of equal amplitude, the result is a sinusoid with a phase that is exactly between the phase of the I signal and the Q signal. But from the first figure in the first All About Circuits link listed here, the cancellation isn't evident to me.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@jsotola unfortunately the OP doesn't understand enough yet to be able to ask a single question.

Neil, thank you for understanding why I could not ask a more focused question.  I attempted to add more information about what I found confusing by including relevant sentences from the links I cited.


I don't understand how QPSK modulation is involved with or assists in
carrier suppression

Let's start with a carrier that has two states; 0° of phase shift and 180° of phase shift. Those two phase shifts are driven by the data that modulates the carrier. Now, if the data is random (or balanced), the carrier frequency is suppressed because it spends equal time in both phase shifted states: -

The green lower waveform is the modulated carrier and, if you did a Fourier analysis you would find that there is no content at the exact frequency of the unmodulated carrier (1 MHz). But there are sidebands that correspond with the spectrum of the modulating signal (a 100 kHz square wave): -

It's a simple trick to extend this to four states such as 0°, 90°, 180° and, 270°. If the data is balanced, the average amplitude of the carrier frequency is zero: -

And the Fourier shows no content at 1 MHz: -

But it does show sidebands at 500 kHz, 1500 kHz, 2500 kHz etc..
This has nothing to do with the modulation method or with the modulation signal (provided it is balanced). It's all to do with  communication theory and math.

It's important to understand the difference between QPSK and IQ modulation.
QPSK, Quadrature Phase Shift Modulation, is a type of modulation, regardless of how it's actually implemented.
IQ modulation, using In phase and Quadrature components, is a method of implementing any type of modulation.
QPSK defines there to be four states for the phase of the signal. With respect to the unmodulated signal these have shifts of 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees. This means that each symbol can carry two bits, as two bits define four options.
Because it's constant amplitude, QPSK can be implemented by taking an oscillator and applying phase modulation, or even frequency modulation, directly to it, so that it takes the correct phase. It can also be generated using IQ.
IQ modulation is a technique to put the carrier into any defined state of phase and amplitude, or complex, modulation. We usually define the modulation The carrier is split into two phases at quadrature to each other. The unshifted part is multiplied with the real part of the desired complex modulation, the 90 degree shifted part is multiplied with the imaginary part. Because each modulated carrier is a real signal, they now have both the wanted signal and its complex conjugate modulated onto them. Because of the relative phasing, one being 0 the other 90 degrees, when these two modulated carriers are recombined, the wanted parts add, the conjugate parts subtract, and ideally cancel, and you are left with just the wanted modulation.
This IQ technique can create any type of modulation. However, as it's more expensive than just amplitude or phase modulating a carrier, it's usually reserved for complex modulation.
